# How come $\{(x, 1/x) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid x > 0\}$ is closed?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I have to give an example of a closed set $W \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ whose projection $p_1[W]$ on the x-axis is not closed in $\mathbb{R}$.

Our teacher has said that we should consider $C = \{(x, 1/x) \mid x \in \Bbb R; x > 0\}$. I can see that **if** the set is closed clearly its projection $(0, \infty)$ on the $x$-axis is open. But how come it is closed? I've looked at it from two perspectives:

Limit points: I know a subset $A$ of a metric space $X$ is closed iff it contains all of its limit points $X$. But $1/x \rightarrow 0 \notin C$ so by that theorem C should be at least not closed?

Definition: $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus C = (\infty, 0] \times (\infty, 0]$ and a cartesian product of to closed sets is closed - so it is not open?

Where am I wrong?

Comment: $1/x$ is not a point in the plane, and $(x, 1/x)$ has no limit point for $x \to \infty$.

Comment: It's also definitely not true that $\mathbb R^2\setminus C = (-\infty,0]^2$. For example $(2,3)\in\mathbb R^2\setminus C$, but $(2,3)\notin(-\infty,0]^2$.

Comment: Your two arguments together give the impression that you don't really understand which set $C$ is. (You're quoting its definition wrong, too -- writing $(x,1/x)\in \mathbb R$ makes little sense). Do you realise that this same set can also be written $\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2\mid x>0, xy=1\}$?

Comment: The easiest way to see that it is closed is this: notice the function of two variables $F:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R, F(x, y)=xy$ is continuous. Known theorem: the inverse image (under continuous function) of a closed set is a closed set. Now, notice that $C=F^{-1}(\{1\})$.

Comment: This set is the graph of the function $y=1/x$ in the upper right quadrant. Now do you see it? (Perhaps your teacher had a typo: it should be $C=\{(x,1/x)\in\Bbb R^2\mid x>0\}$.)

Comment: @Troposphere better yet: $C=\{(x,y)\in \Bbb R^2\mid x\ge 0; xy=1\}$.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma:  I don't get it.

Comment: @TonyK: I think Henno's point was that with $x\ge 0$ instead of $x>0$, we get the same set of points, but now written as the intersection of the two clearly (?) closed sets $\{(x,y)\mid x\ge 0\}$ and $\{(x,y)\mid xy=1\}$.

Answer (score 2):

The function $m: \Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R$ defined by $m(x,y)=xy$ is continuous.

The inverse image of a closed set under a continuous function is closed, and $Q=[0,\infty) \times [0,\infty)$ (closed upper quadrant) is closed in $\Bbb R^2$.

Knowing that it suffices to note that $C= m^{-1}[\{1\}] \cap Q$, hence $C$ is closed as $\{1\}$ is closed in $\Bbb R$.

(if $(x,y) \in C$ we know that $x>0$ and $y=\frac1x>0$ and so $m(x,y)=1$ and also $(x,y) \in Q$; the converse is similar).

Answer (score 0):

To show $C$ is closed, it suffices to show:

If $(a_n,b_n) \in C$ for $n=1,2,3\dots$, and $(a_n,b_n) \to (a,b)$, then $(a,b) \in C$.

Assume $(a_n,b_n) \in C$.  This means: $a_n > 0, b_n > 0, a_nb_n=1$.
Assume $(a_n,b_n) \to (a,b)$.  This means $a_n \to a$ and $b_n \to b$.  From this we conclude $a_nb_n \to ab$, and thus $ab=1$.  We also have $a \ge 0, b\ge 0$, and together with $ab=1$ we get $a>0,b>0$.  Conclude: $(a,b) \in C$.